# code coverage for batch class

Tags: batch, unit-test, scheduled-apex, code-coverage, schedulebatch

How can i get increase coverage for this code? I get only 55% so far.

Also, when I am doing an assert, it should not be equal to '0' but for some reason if i do that then it complains saying it should be 0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you, Manohar

```
global class ISMTrackingBatchProcess implements Database.Batchable < sObject >
{    
    global Database.QueryLocator  start(Database.BatchableContext ctx)
    {
        System.Debug('***** Here it starts *****');
        String Query = 'Select Owner_Name__c, Contact_Name__c,CaseNumber, Owner_Email__c, Dummy_ISM_Datetime__c, TFS_ID__c, Id, ISM_Priority__c, ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c From Case  where Dummy_ISM_Datetime__c <> Null and ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c <> Null and TFS_ID__c <> Null and ISM_Priority__c in (\'Critical\',\'High\')' ;

        return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<sObject> scope)
    {
        integer failedUpdates1;
        integer failedUpdates2;
        List<Case> cs= (List<Case>)scope;
        List<ISM_Communication_Tracker__c> ismcts = new List<ISM_Communication_Tracker__c>();
        List<ISM_Communication_Alert__c> ismcas = new List<ISM_Communication_Alert__c>();
        boolean missflg  ;
        integer missflg10;
        if (cs.size()>0) 
        {        
        for(Integer i = 0; i < cs.size(); i++){
            if (cs[i].ISM_Priority__c == 'Critical' )
            {
                // Send Email ISM Alert Emails
                integer dmincr = (Math.Floor(decimal.valueOf(Datetime.now().getTime() - cs[i].Dummy_ISM_Datetime__c.getTime() )) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0)).intValue();
                for (integer j = 0; j < dmincr; j++){

//Test not covered from here onwards

                    ***task[]  t =[select id from task where whatId = :cs[i].id and createddate >=  :cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j) and createddate <= :cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j).addMinutes(30) and Subject in ('Call','Email') limit 1];
                    if (t.size() == 0 )
                    {
                        ismcas.add(new ISM_Communication_Alert__c(Created_Date_and_Time__c = System.now() , 
                                                                    Case_Owner_Email__c =cs[i].Owner_Email__c, 
                                                                    ISM_Priority__c =cs[i].ISM_Priority__c, 
                                                                    Unique_index__c =cs[i].CaseNumber +string.valueOf(cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j)) + string.valueOf(cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j).addMinutes(30)),
                                                                    Case__c = cs[i].id, 
                                                                    Log_start_at__c = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j), 
                                                                    Log_End_At__c = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j).addMinutes(30), 
                                                                    of_Emails__c = j));
                    }
                }***

////Test not covered until here

                // Create ISM Communication Logs
                integer hrincr = (Math.Floor(decimal.valueOf(Datetime.now().getTime() - cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.getTime() )) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0)).intValue();
                for (integer j = 0; j < hrincr; j++){

//Test not covered from here onwards

                    ***task[]  t =[select id from task where whatId = :cs[i].id and createddate >=  :cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j) and createddate <= :cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j+1) and Subject in ('Call','Email') limit 1];

                    if (t.size() > 0 )
                    {
                        missflg = false;
                        missflg10 = 0;                          
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        missflg = true;
                        missflg10 = 1;
                    }

                    ismcts.add(new ISM_Communication_Tracker__c(Case__c = cs[i].id,
                                                       Missed_Communication__c = missflg,
                                                       Missed_Communication1_0__c = missflg10,
                                                       Log_Start_At__c = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j),
                                                       PrimaryKey__c = string.valueOf(cs[i].id) + string.valueOf(cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c) + cs[i].ISM_Priority__c +  string.valueof(j) , 
                                                       ISM_Priority__c  = cs[i].ISM_Priority__c,
                                                       ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c  = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c,
                                                       Logged_At__c = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j+1),
                                                       of_hrs_since_ISM_Priority_Chnaged__c  =Math.Floor(Decimal.valueOf(cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j+1).getTime() - cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.getTime() )) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0)    
                                                       ));
                }
            }***

////Test not covered until here

            Else if (cs[i].ISM_Priority__c == 'High' )
            {

                // Send Email ISM Alert Emails
                integer dmincr = (Math.Floor(decimal.valueOf(Datetime.now().getTime() - cs[i].Dummy_ISM_Datetime__c.getTime() )) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0)).intValue();
                for (integer j = 0; j < dmincr; j=j+4){

//Test not covered from here onwards

                    task[]  t =[select id from task where whatId = :cs[i].id and createddate >=  :cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j) and createddate <= :cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j).addMinutes(150) and Subject in ('Call','Email') limit 1];

                    if (t.size() == 0 )
                    {
                        ismcas.add(new ISM_Communication_Alert__c(Created_Date_and_Time__c = System.now() ,
                                                                    Case_Owner_Email__c =cs[i].Owner_Email__c, 
                                                                    ISM_Priority__c =cs[i].ISM_Priority__c, 
                                                                    Unique_index__c =cs[i].CaseNumber +string.valueOf(cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j)) + string.valueOf(cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j).addMinutes(150)),
                                                                    Case__c = cs[i].id, 
                                                                    Log_start_at__c = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j), 
                                                                    Log_End_At__c = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j).addMinutes(210), 
                                                                    of_Emails__c = j));
                    }
                }

////Test not covered until here                

                //Create ISM Communication Tracking Log
                integer hrincr = (Math.Floor(decimal.valueOf(Datetime.now().getTime() - cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.getTime() )) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0)).intValue();
                for (integer j = 3; j < hrincr; j=j+4){

//Test not covered from here onwards

                    task[]  t =[select id from task where whatId = :cs[i].id and createddate >=  :cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j-3) and createddate <= :cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j+1) and Subject in ('Call','Email') limit 1];

                    if (t.size() > 0 )
                    {
                        missflg = false;
                        missflg10 = 0;                          
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        missflg = true;
                        missflg10 = 1;
                    }

                    ismcts.add(new ISM_Communication_Tracker__c(Case__c = cs[i].id,
                                                       Missed_Communication__c = missflg,
                                                       Missed_Communication1_0__c = missflg10,
                                                       Log_Start_At__c = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j-3),
                                                       PrimaryKey__c = string.valueOf(cs[i].id) + string.valueOf(cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c) + cs[i].ISM_Priority__c +  +  string.valueof(j-3) , 
                                                       ISM_Priority__c  = cs[i].ISM_Priority__c,
                                                       ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c  = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c,
                                                       Logged_At__c = cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j+1),
                                                       of_hrs_since_ISM_Priority_Chnaged__c  =Math.Floor(Decimal.valueOf(cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.addhours(j+1).getTime() - cs[i].ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c.getTime() )) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0)    
                                                       ));
                }
            }
        }



        failedUpdates1 = 0;
        List<Database.UpsertResult> dsrs1 = Database.upsert(ismcts, false);
        for(Database.UpsertResult dsr1 : dsrs1){
            if(!dsr1.isSuccess()){
                failedUpdates1++;

////Test not covered until here  

            }

        }
        failedUpdates2 = 0;
        List<Database.UpsertResult> dsrs2 = Database.upsert(ismcas, false);
        for(Database.UpsertResult dsr2 : dsrs2){
            if(!dsr2.isSuccess()){
                failedUpdates2++;
            }

        }
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) 
    {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN,'Batch Process Finished');

    }
}
```

This is what I have so far...

```
@isTest
private class testscheduleCriticalISM{


   public static testMethod void testscheduleISMTrackingBatchProcess()
    {
        Test.startTest();
        scheduleISMTrackingBatchProcess s = new scheduleISMTrackingBatchProcess();
        string sch = '0 0 * * 1-12 ? *';
        system.schedule('Process Trans 1', sch, s);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    public static testMethod void testISMTrackingBatchProcess()
    {
        //get the initial details
        Profile pf = [Select Id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator'];

        //creating RunAs User Record
        User u = new User();
        u.FirstName = 'Test';
        u.LastName = 'user';
        u.Email = 'testuser@test123456789.com';
        u.CompanyName = 'test.com';
        u.Title = 'Test user';
        u.Username = 'testuser@test123456789.com';
        u.Alias = 'testuser';
        u.CommunityNickname = 'Test User';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago';
        u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
        u.ProfileId = pf.Id;
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        insert u; 
        Datetime dToday = System.now().addHours(-5);

        String ISM_Priority;
        List <Case> kases = new List<Case>();
        for(integer i = 0; i<200; i++){
            if (i < 100) 
            {    ISM_Priority = 'Critical';}
            else
            {    ISM_Priority = 'High';}
            Case c = new Case(Subject='testCase'+'i', 
                        Ownerid = u.ID,
                        Status = 'Open',
                        Origin = 'Other',
                        TFS_ID__c = i,
                        ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c = origDate,
                        Dummy_ISM_Datetime__c = origDate.addMinutes(-30),
                        ISM_Priority__c = ISM_Priority 
                        ); 

            kases.add(c);
            }
        insert kases;   
        task[]  t =[select id from task where Subject in ('Call','Email') ];


        integer dmincr = (Math.Floor(decimal.valueOf(System.now().getTime() - dToday.addMinutes(-30).getTime() )) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0)).intValue();
        integer hrincr = (Math.Floor(decimal.valueOf(System.now().getTime() - dToday.getTime() )) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0)).intValue();
        Test.startTest();
        ISMTrackingBatchProcess b = new ISMTrackingBatchProcess();
        ID myBatchJobID = database.executebatch(b);     
        Test.stopTest();
        if (t.size() ==0 && hrincr > 4)
        {
            System.AssertEquals(database.countquery('SELECT COUNT() FROM ISM_Communication_Alert__c WHERE ISM_Priority__c  =\'Critical\''), 0);  
        }
        if (t.size() ==0 && dmincr > 4)
        {
            System.AssertEquals(database.countquery('SELECT COUNT() FROM ISM_Communication_Tracker__c WHERE ISM_Priority__c  =\'High\''), 0);  
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that dmincr and hrincr are both > 0? A simple system.debug should do it. If the value is 0 (or less) then this could explain why your loops aren't 'looping'.

Comment: yes they are as I am setting dToday = System.now().addHours(-5); and then using that to get difference. Also, I can see that it has value greater than 0. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Actually you are right Richard, dmincr were setting back to System.now() from a different process and that was not letting it get into to clause. thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @RichardDurrant can you add your solution as an answer below so we can get it marked as a helpful answer? Thanks!

Comment: Btw, you are doing your System.assertEquals backwards.  The first parameter should be the expected value, and the second should be the actual value.  Basically, your 0's should be in front.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that dmincr and hrincr are both > 0? A simple system.debug should do it. If the value is 0 (or less) then this could explain why your loops aren't 'looping'.

Comment: Yes.  This should be the correct answer.  You need to find out what these values are in order to realize why you aren't moving on.

Answer (score -1):

just calling Database.executeBatch does not fully execute your batch job, hence the values dont get incremented. Init a new instance of your batch instance and execute manually

```
static testMethod void myTest(){

    // setup your test data here

    // init batch instance
    ISMTrackingBatchProcess myBatch = new ISMTrackingBatchProcess();

    // query records that would be normally feed from the QueryLocator
    String qry = 'Select Owner_Name__c, Contact_Name__c,CaseNumber, Owner_Email__c, Dummy_ISM_Datetime__c, TFS_ID__c, Id, ISM_Priority__c, ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c From Case  where Dummy_ISM_Datetime__c <> Null and ISM_Priority_Set_Critical_High_At__c <> Null and TFS_ID__c <> Null and ISM_Priority__c in (\'Critical\',\'High\')' ;

    sObject[] scope = Database.query(qry);

    // execute the batch
    myBatch.execute(scope);

    // assert outcome

}
```